# How to make scala shell to show an anonymous function?

Tags: scala

I am learning scala and a typical example is the definition of an anonymous function:

```
scala> (x: Int) => x + 7
res11: Int => Int = <function1>
```

How do I make the shell to show me the body of `<function1>`?
Which would be x + 7 in the above case.

This becomes interesting if a function is partially applied:

```
scala> def adder(m: Int, n: Int) : Int = m + n
adder: (m: Int, n: Int)Int
scala> val add2 = adder(2, _:Int)
add2: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Comment: What do you call the "content" of the function? It could be many different things, some of which are not human readable, and others may be to long to be a suitable `toString` value...

Comment: I don't think you can do this in the repl, however, if you compile a scala file with -Xprint:parser is will print out the code it generates.

Comment: I am gonna try that, thx.

Comment: BTW the "interesting" part is not due to partially applying, but due to having a function (add2) instead of a method (adder).

Comment: good point, I did not see it from that point of view. Nevertheless, I still would like to see what the remaining is in <function1>